# How to make C# objects dynamically override functions?

Tags: c#, object

I'm using XML Deserialization to initialize a lot of objects on start up from an XML file. In the class for the object, I have a calculation function. Each object will have a different way of doing a calculation and needs to be unique for each object. What's the best way to tie this to data for each object? Should I use inheritance and override the calculation function?

Edit: So the base class that's coming from the XML is:

`public class Problem
    {
        public string ProblemName {get; set;}
        public Condition[] LotsOfConditions;
    }
    public class Condition
    {
        public string ConditionName { get; set; }
        public List<string> PropertyNames;
        public List<string> PropertyValues;
    }
}`

My application code has an array of problems that is deserialized from the XML file. I wanted to add a calculation method in the Condition class that would return a result depending on the property names/values loaded into it from the file. Some properties are string compares while others would be parsed into doubles to perform a calculation.

I was thinking of creating new classes with the calculation method that inherited from the Condition class, but I would need a way to tie the proper object with what's in the XML files.

Comment: please give a sample of ur xml file and the type of objects you are creating. What do you mean by each object has a diff calculation function

Comment: You really need to post some code to get this question going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is meant exactly for this kind of situation.

> the strategy pattern (also known as the policy pattern) is a software design pattern that enables an algorithm's behavior to be selected at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would be easier to have the calculation function as delegate and pass the correct calculation function to each object. The actual calculation function of your object would then use the passed method for the calculation function.